# How to check if expiration date is under a month?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a code that checks the number of days left given the expiration date:

```js
const expiration = "2019-10-25T01:41:02.523Z";
const daysLeft = Math.floor((Date.parse(expiration) - Date.now()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

console.log(daysLeft);
```

Now I want to check if the current date is under a month from the given expiration date.

I tried using moment but I'm not sure if I am doing it right

```
const now = moment().add(1, 'M');
const expires = moment(expiration);

if (now.isBefore(expires)) {
  // expired
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're already using `Date.now()` in your calculation for how many daysLeft the expiration is. Why not just do `if (daysLeft < 30)` it's less than a month.

Comment: @FrankerZ I thought of that but... how do I know if I should check it if it's less by 30? It can be 31 or 28/29 right? Or 30 days is the standard for that?

Comment: I think your question is too broad. I think your question is more like checking if the expiration date is within the current month. That is because most people would consider 30 days is within a month.

Comment: @KevinNg updated the title. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to just reverse your logic, and use `isAfter()`. If we log `2019-10-25T01:41:02.523Z` it now shows "under a month", and if we increment that to "2019-11-25" it no longer shows a `console.log` message:

```js
const expiration = "2019-10-25T01:41:02.523Z";

const now = moment().add(1, 'M');
const expires = moment(expiration);

if (now.isAfter(expires)) {
  console.log(expiration, 'under a month');
} else {
  console.log(expiration, 'not under a month');
}


const expiration2 = "2019-11-25T01:41:02.523Z";

const expires2 = moment(expiration2);

if (now.isAfter(expires2)) {
  console.log(expiration2, 'under a month');
} else {
  console.log(expiration2, 'not under a month');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much.